# issue with connecting to WiFi on certain devices

Tags: windows-7, wireless-networking

I have an issue with my home WiFi (virgin superhub) signal. It used to work fine but lately it doesn't seem to work on specific devices. For example, each apple device (laptops, iPhone, iPad etc) seems to work fine and connects with no problem, but when I try to use the internet on my windows laptop, it won't connect to the same WiFi.

I've tried resetting the connection, deleting and then re-connecting to that connection but nothing seems to work. I've also tried to disconnect the other devices in case the WiFi is over crowded, but that didn't help either.

I know everything is fine with the laptop because I can connect to other WiFi's no problem. The same occurs with another windows laptop I've tried with. I also see the message 'Network Security Key Mismatch', which initially made me think that the password was not OK, but nothing has changed on the laptop end i.e. one day it was working and the other day it wasn't. Then all of a sudden it stopped working on two different devices.

Answer (score 0):

Could your router be using the same SSID for both 5GHz and 2.4GHz? I've found from experience that some devices fail to connect properly unless I give the 2.4GHz and 5GHz channels different SSIDs. Newer routers use the same SSID and then serve the correct channel to the device dependent on what it can accept

Comment: I'm not sure. How would I check this and make the neccesary changes?

Comment: You'd need to log into your router. Not sure how this is done on the virgin media routers but a quick search on the internet would show you.